# NotificationManager: cancel(id) DON'T work

Tags: java, android, xml

From a Service, I show a Notification. I have this code:

```
    public final static int NOTIFICATION = 1;   
    public final static int NOTIFICATION2 = 2;

case NOTIFICATION2:
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_about);
                builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                            builder.setContentInfo(i+"/"+10);
                            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION2, builder.build());
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }               
                }).start(); 
                notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION2);
break;
```

The code works fine, but when the thread is finished the Notification remain. Why? I want to cancel it and `cancel()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Because you start your asynchronous thread which displays the notification, `notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION2);` is called immediately. That means that your notification was not displayed yet, when you cancelled it.

Try to move `notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION2);` into the run() method.

Comment: So? How can i delete the notification when Thread is finished?

Comment: Try to move `notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION2);` into the run() method (at the end).